# Проблема со слайдером на html css

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper {
 height: 550px;
 margin: 100px auto 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 90%;
 right: 0px;
 top: 150px;
}

.slider {
 height: inherit;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 width: inherit;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
 -o-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.slides {
 height: inherit;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: inherit;
 z-index: 0;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
 -o-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform: scale(1.5);
 -webkit-transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, opacity ease-in-out .5s;
 -moz-transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, opacity ease-in-out .5s;
 -o-transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, opacity ease-in-out .5s;
 transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, opacity ease-in-out .5s;
}

.slide1 { background-image: url(transport.jpg); }
.slide2 { background-image: url(expertisa.jpg); }
.slide3 { background-image: url(sltorg.jpg); }


#slide1:checked ~ .slider > .slide1,
#slide2:checked ~ .slider > .slide2,
#slide3:checked ~ .slider > .slide3,
 {
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -o-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
}

.wrapper > input {
 display: none;
}

.wrapper .controls {
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -68px;
 top: 50px;
 position: absolute;
}

.wrapper label {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 8px;
 margin: 25px 12px 0 16px;
 position: relative;
 width: 8px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -o-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-transition: background ease-in-out .5s;
 -moz-transition: background ease-in-out .5s;
 -o-transition: background ease-in-out .5s;
 transition: background ease-in-out .5s;
}

.wrapper label:hover {
#slide1:checked ~ .controls label:nth-of-type(1),
#slide2:checked ~ .controls label:nth-of-type(2),
#slide3:checked ~ .controls label:nth-of-type(3),}
{
 background: #ddd;
}

.wrapper label:after {
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 content: " ";
 display: block;
 height: 12px;
 left: -4px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -4px;
 width: 12px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -o-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <input type="radio" name="point" id="slide1" checked>
 <input type="radio" name="point" id="slide2">
 <input type="radio" name="point" id="slide3">

 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slides slide1"></div>
  <div class="slides slide2"></div>
  <div class="slides slide3"></div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="controls">
  <label for="slide1"></label>
  <label for="slide2"></label>
  <label for="slide3"></label>
 
 </div>
</div>
```

НЕ отображает картинки и нет анимации на кнопки
Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил я чуть чуть стилизацию и в общем если что то не ясно спрашивайте ..я отвечу

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 350px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.slides {
  height: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  -moz-transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  -o-transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, opacity ease-in-out .5s;
}

.slide1 {
  background: red;
}

.slide2 {
  background: green;
}

.slide3 {
  background: blue;
}

#slide1:checked~.slider>.slide1,
#slide2:checked~.slider>.slide2,
#slide3:checked~.slider>.slide3 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.wrapper>input {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper .controls {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 101;
  padding: 0 20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wrapper label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: background ease-in-out .5s;
  -moz-transition: background ease-in-out .5s;
  -o-transition: background ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: background ease-in-out .5s;
}

.wrapper label:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.wrapper label:hover,
#slide1:checked~.controls label:nth-of-type(1),
#slide2:checked~.controls label:nth-of-type(2),
#slide3:checked~.controls label:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #ddd;
}

.wrapper label:after {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  left: -4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  width: 12px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="point" id="slide1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="point" id="slide2">
  <input type="radio" name="point" id="slide3">

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides slide1"></div>
    <div class="slides slide2"></div>
    <div class="slides slide3"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <label for="slide1"></label>
    <label for="slide2"></label>
    <label for="slide3"></label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: С этим справилась,спасибо! Теперь наложила содержимое и получилась каша, поможете?